# Can I delete previous Anki backups on my iPhone and keep just the latest?

Tags: ios, backup, storage

I use Anki on my laptop, iPad and iPhone.

My iPhone is running out of storage and I need to delete some stuff. I’ve noticed that I have multiple anki backups that take up a bunch of space. If I were to delete all backups and keep the latest, would that affect my cards history?

Let’s say I studied a card on Monday and won’t see it till next week, I studied other cards on Tuesday, Wednesday, … If I delete all backups except the one from Wednesday, is the history from that card I studied on Monday preserved? I don’t know if what I’m saying is making sense but I don’t know how else to explain what I’m thinking.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As you can see in the attached picture, there a multiple backups for my anki deck. I was just wondering if I were to delete them all except the lastest would thay keep the memory of all my flashcards intact? @Community

Comment: Wouldn't that be a question for the software developer?